# gstreamer 1.0 and raspberry pi streaming from webcam to ios browser

Tags: ios, raspberry-pi, gstreamer, h.264, http-live-streaming

Using gstreamer 1.0, I would like to create a pipeline that streams video from a Logitech C920 webcam to an iphone running chrome ios. This pipeline would run on a raspberry pi model B. I think I need to use hlssink, and serve a m3u8 file. I was thinking of running a python-tornado webserver to serve the m3u8 file on the raspberry pi. Also I know that the Logitech C920 supports hardware encoding for H.264 and would like to use that if possible. So far I've been unsuccessful and would appreciate any help or feedback.

Comment: Do you need help building the GStreamer pipeline that creates transport stream fragments and m3u8 file with the webcam video?

Comment: Did you try gst-rtsp-server? It might be useful for streaming to browser.

Comment: @jgorosdev - Yes, I need help creating a GStreamer pipeline. Do you have an example you can share that works ?

Comment: @Alper Kucukkomurler - Do you have an example you can share that shows how it works ?

Comment: Have you already tested that you're capturing ok from the webcam? Launching for example: _gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! xvimagesink_

Comment: Yes it works with v4l2src device=/dev/video0 and autovideosink. Worst case I can use videotestsrc at the beginning to simplify testing the hls pipeline. I just need an example of a working hls pipeline to begin with that sends the stream to an apple chrome ios browser

Comment: @Francis you can download the source code from htps://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-rtsp-server/ after you build it you can run the test-launch app like gst-launch-1.0. (for example `./test-launch filesrc location="myfile.m3u8" ! decodebin ! videoconvert ...`) Then you need to add this to your html page.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the *minimal* hlssink pipeline is like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc is-live=true ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink max-files=5
```

You need to encode the raw source from the camera with `x264enc` and parse then with `h264parser`. After that you need to multiplex different media streams into an MPEG Transport Stream (in this case we have only video).

The final pipeline would be, for example:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc is-live=true ! video/x-raw, framerate=25/1, width=720, height=576, format=I420 ! x264enc bitrate=1000 key-int-max=25 ! h264parse ! video/x-h264 ! queue ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink playlist-length=10 max-files=20 playlist-root="http://localhost/hls/" playlist-location="/var/www/html/hls/stream0.m3u8" location="/var/www/html/hls/fragment%06d.ts" target-duration=5
```

I have added some caps to help you adding after `v4l2src device=/dev/video0`, but this depends on the camera model. I also added some different *properties* from `hlssink` to show you how to set the different files location.The pipeline above runs with videotestsrc and writes the files and playlist in `/var/www/html/hls` folder.
Tested with *Apache*, it is possible to view the result with vlc or simply running:

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=http://localhost/hls/stream0.m3u8
```

If you have any doubts capturing from webcam you can follow this [link](http://wiki.oz9aec.net/index.php/Gstreamer_cheat_sheet#Webcam) for more information.